# Different image color on computer vs smartphone/tablet

Tags: css, image, mobile, colors, png

So I'm working on website for someone the logo and background should match 
But when I tested it on mobile, I noticed that the colors were off and that the logo image and the background colors don't blend together anymore because they're seemingly different colors.

link : 
http://students.washington.edu/jgb93/shiningprince/shiningprince/jpnIndex.html#/home

I tested on macbook pro - without the retina screen, while my iPad, and iPhone are both more recent generations - with retina.

The color of Bg is : `#A692AB`.

Comment: everything is ok for me.. once color is white then second is purple..what you want?

Comment: Try to search "screen calibration mackbook" example : http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/. You can read the articles on the topic "color reproduction of the screen" to better understand the problem.

Comment: @Gregorie I'll try reading through it, but I don't think it has to do with screen calibration because on my computer, the image, and the color I got from the color-grabber website blend seamlessly.  The problem comes when I view it in mobile - and the weird part is that when I do the color-grabber on my mobile device, it gives me a different hex color code. Screen calibration shouldn't affect the color a web-app like that would spit out, would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the color of the image is `#A492AD`

and the one of site is `#A692AB`
see latest letter in website B and in image D

just change this part ( main.css ) line 46 to this

```
 #jp, #jpBody, #jpFooter {
     background-color: #A492AD;
 }
```

if this did not work just put and image with no BG ( png image )

Comment: Thanks, still didn't work, but I'll go with the no background image.

Answer (score 1):

The image background color is #A08DA8 so you need to change the image or the body CSS.

For example, change this:

```
#jp, #jpBody, #jpFooter {
    background-color: #A692AB;
}
```

To this:

```
#jp, #jpBody, #jpFooter {
    background-color: #A08DA8;
}
```

To make them the same color

Comment: Appreciate the response!  However, I tried it out and am still getting a very slight difference in color.  May I ask what method you used to get that color code?  And do you think it's possible that it's just my computer?

Comment: Any tools should be see the JP image background as #A08DA8. Hexcodes won't change in the way that you describe.

Comment: @Julian If you have tried it, please link to a screenshot in a comment - thanks

Comment: Hm weird, well, I'll keep that color code saved somewhere, and maybe try to get access to other computers to check the website on. Edit: Good idea on trying to link a photo - I'll try that now.

Comment: @Julian Huh. Maybe making the image with a transparent background is the best way forward.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right.  Thanks for checking that out for me, anyway.  I'll try to see if I can get the original illustrator file to get a transparent background.